# Show the location of Safeway by ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I want to show the location of Safeway store in Seaside, Oregon with the following coordinates: 
(-123.9215,45.99102).
It shows the middle of the street! I have shown the Google earth picture, the correct one. There is a little bit difference.

```
seaside <- get_map(location = c(lon = -123.9215, lat =45.99102), maptype = 
c("satellite") ,zoom = 16)
SeasideMap <- ggmap(seaside, extent = "device", legend = "topleft")

d <- data.frame(lon=c(-123.9215),lat=c(45.99102))

p <- SeasideMap + geom_point(data=d,  aes(x=lon, y=lat), color="red", 
size=30, alpha=0.5)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: The coordinate you give is in the middle of street.

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure your coordinates are right?

When I do

```
geocode("Safeway, Seaside, Oregon")
```

I get lon = -123.9201, lat = 45.99097

Which looks like it's smack on top of a large building, I'm assuming Safeway.

Comment: Google Earth shows (-123.9201,45.99) as a building (Safeway), but ggmap shows the middle of the street close to it!

Answer (score 0):

Confirming what others have said, your coordinates are 'incorrect'; they are actually for the street entrance to the car park.

In this example I'm plotting a marker at the coordinates you've given. Then I'm 'searching' in the search box for 'Safeway', and you can see it's plotted the 'shopping bag' icon over the shop.

```
library(googleway)

map_key <- "map_api_key"

d <- data.frame(lon=c(-123.9215),lat=c(45.99102))

google_map(key = map_key, search_box = T) %>%
    add_markers(data = d)
```

[image]

In this image you can see the carpark entrance is where the marker is

[image]

Which is then evidenced by geocoding the store

```
res <- google_geocode(address = "Safeway, Seaside, Oregon", key = "api_key")

res$results$geometry
  location.lat location.lng location_type viewport.northeast.lat viewport.northeast.lng viewport.southwest.lat
1     45.99097    -123.9201   APPROXIMATE               45.99232              -123.9188               45.98962
  viewport.southwest.lng
1              -123.9215
```

Comment: Ok, then my question is why Google Earth shows (-123.9215,45.99) as a building as I shown, but ggmap shows the middle of the street?   
Is res$results$geometry the geometry of Safeway as you searched? If so, I think (-123.9215,45.99) should be for Safeway. Am I right?

Comment: @GulfChanter `res$results$geometry` is the geometry of the Safewary search, where `location.lat = 45.99097` and `location.lng = -123.9201` are the coordinates given by the search result.